# SpriteKit Map Creation Through Image Pixels

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift, ios8

I recently downloaded a project made by apple with SpriteKit to have a look at their code and I noticed something that looked quite interesting. They created their entire map using an image

(project link below- image found at AdventureShared/Assets/Environment/map_level.png)

by taking it apart pixel by pixel. I can't seem the find the code by which they do this in the project but would like some idea on how to do something similar. If anyone could either show me where i can find the code in the project or advise me on how i could replicate the procedure, it would be greatly appreciated. I will give a link to the project below as i am not sure if i can show the code as it is pre-release for iOS8. Thanks a lot!

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/Adventure-Swift/Listings/Adventure_Adventure_Shared_AI_ChaseAI_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014639-Adventure_Adventure_Shared_AI_ChaseAI_swift-DontLinkElementID_4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [code:Explained Adventure](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/AdventureArchitecture/AdventureArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013140) in there the developers break down exactly how the world generation works, including the pixel mapping and why they chose that method.

Answer (score 0):

Some  additional info on how it can be done:

This picture is merely to guide the game designer in the construction of the .sks file
 https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/Art/map_collision_2x.png

However these images below are texture atlases made by dividing an image of size 4096 by 4096 into 32 tiles by 32,(approximately a 1000 tiles in total).

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/Art/background_texture_atlas_2x.png

To generate these tiles I used gimp. I downloaded a script called to grid to guides and then after using that new tool to make a grid across the image, I went to Filters>Web>Slice and generated all the Tiles. Swift automatically takes the individual tiles and configures them into a texture atlas if they are contained in a file called name.atlas